# If a convex quadrilateral is inscribed and circumscribed and has perpendicular diagonals, then one diagonal divides it into congruent right triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> A convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed and circumscribed. If the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ are perpendicular, show that one of them divides the quadrilateral into two congruent right triangles.

The first question I asked myself is how we determine which of the diagonals divides $ABCD$ in the desired way.

If $AB=a,BC=b,CD=c,AD=d$, then $a+c=b+d$ on one hand. Also we have $A+C=B+D=180^\circ$. I tried to do something with the areas. $$S_{ABC}=\dfrac12ab\sin B\\S_{ACD}=\dfrac12cd\sin D\\S_{ABCD}=\dfrac12ab\sin B+\dfrac12cd\sin D=\dfrac12\sin B(ab+cd)\\S_{ABCD}=\dfrac{AC\cdot BD}{2}$$ I don't really think anything of that helps. How to approach the problem?

Comment: Such a figure is called a [**bicentric** quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_quadrilateral) which is [**orthodiagonal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodiagonal_quadrilateral)

Comment: See [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-orthodiagonal-bicentric_fig8_266032395) fig. 6 in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the diagonals intersect at $O$ and set: $a=AO$, $b=BO$, $c=CO$, $d=DO$.

The sums of opposite sides must be the same, giving:
$$
\strut\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}=
\sqrt{a^2+d^2}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}.
$$
Squaring and simplifying we get:
$$
(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=
(a^2+d^2)(b^2+c^2),
$$
which reduces to
$$
(a^2-c^2)(b^2-d^2)=0.
$$
Hence, $a=c$ or $b=d$, that is one of the diagonals bisects the other one and is thus a diameter of the circumscribed circle.